# Register separate service-worker for each page?

Tags: service-worker

I have multiple pages in my application, for example, http://example.com/path/foo1.html and http://example.com/path/foo2.html. Can I register a separate service worker for each of these pages, or do they have to share the same service worker because they are both under ./path folder? In other words, does the scope setting specify a folder, or can scope specify a page? I tried separately registering service workers, one for each page, but what I am seeing is that both service workers are being loaded for each page. Is that expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can register multiple service worker for different pages as long as the 
scope specified is different. Since the root for both the pages is '/path', 
everything after the path will be controlled by the same service worker.

For registering multiple service workers, you need the pages to be moved to different path. or atleast include something between root and html page.

> path/samp/foo1.html and path/samp1/foo2.html

In above case, in foo1.html, you can register the service worker with scope as path/samp and in foo2.html, scope as path/samp1.

Enabling multiple service worker for the same scope is not currently available.

For more info: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/921

Comment: It turns out the scope can specify a page, it doesn't have to be a folder. See https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#scope-match-algorithm